# Specify different groupId for parent POM than children

Tags: java, maven-2

I would like to create a Maven Parent POM file with a groupId of `com.company.maven`, which gives its children a default groupId of `com.company`. Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Also, it flies in the face of the [Maven Guide to Naming Conventions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html), which recommends that (if anything), the child modules should append to the parent groupId, not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the parent pom like:

```
<project...>

  <groupId>com.company.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>..</version>
...
</project>
```

and define in the child pom:

```
<project...>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>..</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>

</project>
```

In other words it's possible to do so but i wouldn't do it cause i would have named the parent "com.company" whereas the child "com.company.maven". I would compare the groupId with the java package name which represent folders so your idea of setting the groupId doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Like a java class, that doesn't know "its" subclasses, a parent pom does not know its child poms. So the parent pom will not be able to set or overwrite attributes of it's children.